# Capturing and organising UX issues in Jira or similar ticketing systems

Tags: jira, methodology, backlog, prioritization, categorization

We use Jira for bugs but sometimes we get useful UX related issues and suggestions that we can't work on straight away but also don't want to loose. How are people using Jira or other similar systems to do this?
I suppose we could use labels to group issues, like identify the product, UI component, task etc then put them in a backlog? Or maybe extract tickets into a completely different system, like Monday?
Is there any recommended workflow or does anyone have any experiences? Software or application doesn't matter, just the process.

Comment: The question is about how you capture UX issues, workflows for managing them, possibly a taxonomy for tagging and generally tapping into experiences a process that I can imagine is quite common for UX practitioners, but thanks for the input.

Comment: What is the difference between a "UX related issue" and a "bug"? A bug, or more appropriately, a defect, is any kind of deficiency that leads to the product not meeting requirements or otherwise needing to be repaired. How is one of your "UX related issues" not a deficiency that needs to be repaired and why doesn't your defect or bug management process work for this type of work?

Comment: Why do you only have bugs in your backlog? Are you a maintenance team? You can use Jira for a lot of things not just bugs. And even if Jira might not be the most friendly of tools to configure, you still have a lot of configuration options at your disposal.

Comment: Why are UX issues considered an externality for your project or team?

Answer (score 1):

Jira has a "components" feature that helps you to group similar issues into meaningful subsets. We can create components like;

1. Frontend
2. Backend
3. API
4. UX
5. UI
6. etc...

For detailed information, please see [this link](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/organize-work-with-components/) from Jira

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think my 'Jira-fu' is weak. I'll check it out.

Comment: This is probably the correct answer from a "How to do it in Jira" point of view, but doesn't really address the OP's underlying process problem. I'm commenting rather than voting because I think it's the most apt so far, but I think there should be a flag on the play for the process. :)

Answer (score 0):

As the existing answer mentions, Jira has a components field that you can use. You also have labels. You can also create an epic or story named something like "UI/UX improvements" and capture the suggestions there as stories or sub-tasks, respectively. Jira also alows you to create your own issue types. So if you have "bug" already, you can create "ui improvement" or whatever (the issue type might be the most clear way to record the suggestions, I think).

> We use Jira for bugs [...]

Jira is used for project execution. Bugs, stories, epics, tasks, configurations, UI/UX design, etc. You don't have just bugs. A product backlog contains all kinds of work items. And most likely you can use the same workflow for UI/UX suggestions, just like you use for bugs.

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned above, I think the issue is that I don't have a deeper understanding of what is possible with Jira.

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on who decides when (and how) to pick them up. Are you eventually passing these over to a PM? Or are you deciding when to pick up what in your team? What other priorities are these tickets contending against?

You need to answer these, to be able to make a decision here, based on what other stakeholders you need involved (PMs? devs? leads? other design teams?), what the process needs to be (approvals? workshops? or just pick up tickets from a backlog?)...

I'd recommend staying in JIRA at the moment, or using something that is more flexible, but can integrate with JIRA (for example Miro).

In general, what you're describing is a product management platform, where you can prioritize based on different perspectives etc. (like Productboard or the new Atlassian Product Discovery platform).